# Why the speed and current will decrease when I change the connection delta to star on ac motor?but reduce motor voltage will have opposite result?

Tags: voltage, current, motor, speed

On the 3phase motor, The motor has been accelerated to a stable operating speed, then I reduce the line voltage -> speed decrease -> slip increase -> current increase -> the power will constant.
But I change the connection from delta to star -> the phase voltage decrease (380V -> 220V), the speed decrease to 1/3, phase current decrease to 1/root3, decrease to power 1/3.

Why the speed and current will decrease when I change the connection delta to star on ac motor,but I reduce the motor voltage will increase the current and speed?

Comment: If the motor speed decreases then, unless more torque has been applied by the mechanical load, power will not be constant. Have you tried reducing the delta line voltage from 380 volts to 220 volts?

Comment: The speed will not reduce. Speed is given by N=120f/poles. The available torque will drop which will cause a very small decrease in speed due to increased slip.